# Параллельный вывод коллекций Dictionary

Tags: c#, коллекции

Добрый день.
Есть коллекция `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`, в которой хранятся значения по типу :

```
<"One", {Prop1,Prop2,Prop3,Prop4}>

<"Two", {EProp1,EProp2,EProp3,EProp4}>
```

Вопрос:

Как вывести в консоль значения коллекции параллельно?

Чтобы результат выглядел приблизительно так:

Prop1 | EProp1

Prop2 | EProp2

Prop3 | EProp3

Prop4 | EProp4

Спасибо.

Comment: А как задаётся правило соответствия ключей? Т.е. "One" ~ "Two", а дальше?

Comment: может быть как 2 ключа, так и несколько. количество не назначено.

Comment: Тогда уточняйте вопрос, что же именно Вы хотите получить. Желательно с обозначениями из теории множеств...

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "вывести значения"? стандартный вывод в консоль?

Comment: Да, для начала просто вывести в консоль значения каждого ключа параллельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при условии заранее известной длины `List<string>`, как-то так:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", DictData.Select(di => di.Key)));
Console.WriteLine("");

for (int i = 0; i < ListLength; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t",  DictData.Select(di => di.Value[i])));            
}
```

https://ideone.com/0k1Dye

т.е просто циклом по длине `List<string>` выбираем значения из каждого "ключа"

Comment: Чем же вам так Aggregate нравится что вы про string.Join забыли?!..